# React - multiple function calls on settimer

Tags: reactjs, settimeout

What I am trying to achieve is to run two functions when timer is up in my React chat app to log user out and show certain UI after timed out log out. These are what I have tried:

**1.**

```
timeOut = () => {
    this.logoutTimeout = setTimeout(this.logoutUser, this.props.timeoutLogoutUser, 100);
}
```

With this code above only the first function runs (logoutUser). If I swap them like so only timeoutLogoutUser runs:

**2.**

```
timeOut = () => {
    this.logoutTimeout = setTimeout(this.props.timeoutLogoutUser, this.logoutUser , 100);
}
```

**3.**
I tried this as well:

```
timeOut = () => {
this.logoutTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.logoutUser;
      this.props.timeoutLogoutUser
    }, 100);
}
```

which gives an error: `Line 28:7:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions`

**4.** ***so this should be working but it is not***

```
timeOut = () => {
    this.logoutTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.timeoutLogoutUser(); //doesn't run
      this.logoutUser(); //runs
    }, 100);
}
```

DETAILED:

ALONE IT RUNS!

```
timeOut = () => {
    this.logoutTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.timeoutLogoutUser();
    }, 100);
}
```

ALONE IT RUNS!

```
   timeOut = () => {
        this.logoutTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
          this.logoutUser();
        }, 100);
    }
```

**5.**

```
  timeOut = () => {
      this.logoutTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.timeoutLogoutUser(() => {
          this.logoutUser(); //doesn't run
      });
      }, 100);
}
```

**ADDITONAL INFORMATION**

```
timeoutLogoutUser = () => { this.setState({timedOutSession: true}) }

logoutUser = (e) => {
    let username = localStorage.getItem('localStoredName');
    let userKey = localStorage.getItem('localStoredUserKey');
    let userRef = firebase.database().ref('users');
    userRef.child(userKey).remove();
    localStorage.clear();
    window.location.replace({pathname: '/'
  });
}
```

Comment: Is it not possible to move `this.props.timeoutLogoutUser();` into `this.logoutUser()` ? I would expect the same call to logout a user though. Not sure why you have 2

Comment: No, because this.logoutUser() gets triggered on a button click logout only and both would be triggered on timeout. (logs out user (this.logoutUser) and shows a modal component on timeout for the user (timeoutLogoutUser()).

Comment: Option 4 is the correct way to call it, out of all of them. Options 1, 2 and 3 will not work. You mentioned "not both of the function gets called" which one does get called?

Comment: In option 4 no matter which function is first this.logoutUser() gets called, and this.props.timeoutLogoutUser() doesn't.

Comment: difficult to tell as is. Is it possible to provide a minimum set of code which reproduces the result? maybe on codesandbox

Comment: @Gabriella, as mentioned above by Gandzal, 4th option of calling setTimeout is correct and it should trigger both the functions.If any of the function is not called then it is not an issue with setTimeout . You need to check if you are passing "timeoutLogoutUser()" as a props.

Comment: I am passing timeoutLogoutUser as props because if I call only that in setTimeout it runs perfectly.  Could be anything to do with that I am setting parent's state when calling this function? I will provide more code in sandbox if not sorted.

Comment: What if you try instead of curly braces just normal  parenthesis inside the setTimeout arrow function?

Answer (score 0):

It's simply a function names collision, rename your function from `setTimeout` to something else (not being an in-built Javascript function's name) and use the approach no. 4 and you'll be all set.

Comment: I have renamed it. Still the same.